# How to start with enyo.js on window OS

Tags: enyo

## Now I have to work on enyo.js and echonest.I am new to this.So please anyone tell me in which IDE I should start working with enyo.js and how to start step by step. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any IDE that has a text editor will suffice :)

Start here:

http://enyojs.com/docs

Also, take a look at the Sampler app:

http://enyojs.com/sampler

Answer (score 2):

The suggested/recommended IDE for enyo is ARES: [github link for ares IDE](https://github.com/enyojs/ares-project)

For initial usage guidelines you can refer this video demo: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qQkzUDtiC-I

And for further details n commonly asked questions refer this : http://forums.enyojs.com/categories/ares, so that you can get some basic ideas about progress and all.